# How to send and receive data multiple times using TCPSocket in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpsocket

How do I send and receive data multiple times using TCPSocket?

```
require 'socket'

TCPSocket.open("example.com", 80) {|s|
  s.send "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", 0
  puts s.read

  s.send "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", 0
  # Here is no data. PS: Without reconnect.
  puts s.read
}
```

I searched but did not find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is that you cannot easily do that using a TCPSocket (it can probably be done but not worth your trouble).
In case of HTTP the server will close the connection after sending the response.

What you want to do is use something that does HTTP and also understands how to do keep-alive's (i.e. persistent) on the connection so that you can reuse the connection. For some background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Look at:
http://www.slideshare.net/HiroshiNakamura/rubyhttp-clients-comparison
slide 30. may be outdated but will give you a good starting point.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad example code. Assume the web server not close the connection, how to do?Thank you!

Comment: you need to understand how the keep-alive works to be able to leverage it. Basically the client has to request it via a header and attempt to reuse the connection. Would suggest you use a library that already know how to do this instead of reinventing the wheel here